# Java 2D Game looks like 3D

Tags: 2d, 3d, java

i have fair experience with java game programming,
i already made a simple mario game (side-Scrolling) 
i'm wondering how can i make a "Java" Game like that 

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utwtXEYW1L0
or that
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqz4dunlhX4
the main problem is that i don't know how to make a 2D game looks like 3D 
i just need a tutorial or the idea behind such things.
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: The idea behind is to use "pre-rendered" sprites to make it look like 3D, and some tricks to create the perspective and relief illusion.

Comment: i guess that i need some explanation :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To elaborate on Valkea's comment, the trick is to use 2D sprites just as you would in a "true" 2D game, but shade and style them to give a sense of depth.  The game feels 2D because your character has realistic shading that appears 3D, and because the map is constructed so that your character can go behind objects. This is achieved by making your character walk on a 2D space, but partially obscuring your view of him when he goes behind a wall (such as the wall transparency shown from your first link).

Dynamic shadows like those shown in your second link are trickier and uncommon. I would look into the "Sunburn Engine" mentioned in the description of that second video for more details.

Answer (score -3):

If your serious about making proper games with java then you need to stop using stuff like Swing, AWT and Java2D and pick up a proper OpenGL binding, e.g. LWJGL or use a games library built on top of an OpenGL binding, like Slick2D, Ardor3D, jMonkeyEngine, jPCT, Xith3D or LibGDX.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question at all; you're just telling him that he is doing it wrong because you say so.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.